# jQuery to get posts by ajax causes browser to crash

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a social networking site and on the main feed page I have written some jQuery so that as the user scrolls down when they get near the bottom of the page the next set of posts is retrieved with ajax and appended to the DOM. The browser gets slower after each ajax request though and by the 3rd or 4th one it crashes. Here is my code:

```
    feed_offset = posts_offset = post_comments_offset = 0;
    loading_posts = loading_post_comments = loading_feed = false;
    posts_end = post_comments_end = feed_end = false;

/* Automatically get new posts as the user scrolls down */
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($('body').height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() + 100)) {
            // get more posts
            if($('#all').is(':visible')) { // more of everything for all tab
                if(loading_feed==false && feed_end==false) {

                    loading_feed = true;
                    $('#all .span12.columns .loading').show();

                    $.post('/feed/ajax_get_more_feed/'+feed_offset, function(data) {
                        $('#all .span12.columns .loading').hide().before(data);
                        feed_offset+= 10;
                        loading_feed = false;
                        if(data=='') {
                            feed_end = true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else if($('#posts').is(':visible')) { // more posts for posts tab
                if(loading_posts==false && posts_end==false) {

                    loading_posts = true;
                    $('#posts .span12.columns .loading').show();

                    $.post('/feed/ajax_get_more_feed_posts/'+posts_offset, function(data) {
                        $('#posts .span12.columns .loading').hide().before(data);
                        posts_offset+= 10;
                        loading_posts = false;
                        if(data=='') {
                            posts_end = true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else { // more post comments for post comments tab
                if(loading_post_comments==false && post_comments_end==false) {

                    loading_post_comments = true;
                    $('#post_comments .span12.columns .loading').show();

                    $.post('/feed/ajax_get_more_feed_post_comments/'+post_comments_offset, function(data) {
                        $('#post_comments .span12.columns .loading').hide().before(data);
                        post_comments_offset+= 10;
                        loading_post_comments = false;
                        if(data=='') {
                            post_comments_end = true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I should add that everything was running fine until i added this code and it's doing this in all browsers.

I've found the problem! Its because I was using a class rather than an ID. So where I had the following:

```
$('#all .span12.columns .loading').hide().before(data);
```

I've changed the item with a class of loading to an id of loading and done this instead:

```
$('#all .span12.columns #loading').hide().before(data);
```

I'm guessing using a class was making jquery have to search the entire DOM whereas with an ID it knows theres only 1 item so the search can stop when its found it

Comment: What happens to the memory footprint of the browser as you load in more data each time?

Comment: It goes up each time, a lot! In firefox on page load it was using approximately 250,000k of memory this went up with each subsequent ajax request by the third request it peaked at around 500,000k and then crashed!

Comment: You are adding more and more data into the page, which takes up memory (you may also be leaking other memory in your Javascript, I haven't checked). It's likely that eventually the web browser runs into problems with this. And so we learn the principal problem with infinite scrolling.

Comment: The data returned by the ajax call is only approximately 1.5k in size though so it shouldn't have a massive effect should it? Lots of sites use infinite scrolling and manage to make it work

Comment: It'll unpack to more in the browser's memory, but that does still seem extreme. I'd go looking for objects created and leaked in your Javascript, or get ready for some pretty detailed tracing and fiddling to find the problem. Definitely sounds like memory to me, although I could be wrong. And I'd suggest that "lots of sites" don't get infinite scrolling right; perhaps half a dozen I've seen manage it, and even Twitter & Facebook have had some performance problems related to this. They don't crash though…

Comment: Are there any good tools to use to detect memory leaks and where they're coming from?

Comment: Google suggests both Microsoft and Firefox have something helpful: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=javascript%20memory%20leaks%20detector&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=af0f8861131591a6&ix=seb&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1289&bih=963

Comment: Have you used a tool like Fiddler and watch the http traffic, are you seeing anything crazy going on like tons of Ajax calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem! Its because I was using a class rather than an ID. So where I had the following:

```
$('#all .span12.columns .loading').hide().before(data);
```

I've changed the item with a class of loading to an id of loading and done this instead:

```
$('#all .span12.columns #loading').hide().before(data);
```

I'm guessing using a class was making jquery have to search the entire DOM whereas with an ID it knows theres only 1 item so the search can stop when its found it

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that you are working on a social network site , it might be a case that you are having multiple ajax calls at a time.
Try to have sequential Ajax calls or kill previos Ajax calls using abort before posting a new ajax call.

Comment: I've found the problem! Its because I was using a class rather than an ID. So where I had the following:

    $('#all .span12.columns .loading').hide().before(data);

I've changed the item with a class of loading to an id of loading and done this instead:

    $('#all .span12.columns #loading').hide().before(data);

I'm guessing using a class was making jquery have to search the entire DOM whereas with an ID it knows theres only 1 item so the search can stop when its found it